# How to write a batch file that will execute the vb.net console application in every 5 min

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net console application. That needs to be run in every 5 min. How to wire a batch file to call that exe file and execute in every 5min. Like an agent.

As suggested, I have written a .bat file like this and saved it as a .bat file and put in my bin folder

%~dp0MyconsoleApp>>%~dp0MyconsoleApp_Log.txt

I have created a windows task scheduler that can execute this for every 5 min.

Now, My question is How to stop this service...  (i am using ctrl+c) What is the best way to start and stop the service...(programatically or manually)

Comment: Why not just use the Task Scheduler built into the OS?

Comment: Perhaps a [Windows Service](http://msmvps.com/blogs/joacim/archive/2009/09/13/creating-a-windows-service-using-vb-net.aspx) would make more sense for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write another VB.net program with a timer and a NotifyIcon. Have the timer start the console application every 5 min, and have a right click option on the NotifyIcon to start/stop manually.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a batch:

```
:start
echo put your file to execute here
echo five minutes break
TIMEOUT /T 300 /NOBREAK
echo I'm back
goto start
```

But like Bill said, the Task Scheduler may be sufficient.